# I'm getting ACPI BIOS error while booting into Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I was upgrading my Ubuntu 20.4 and it shows black screen with "[93.434787] ACPI BIOS error(bug) : could not resolve symbol [_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (2020052B/psargs-330)
ACPI ERROR: aborting method....and so on

Comment: What are you running?  You say Ubuntu 20.04, but then have tagged three flavors? so which are you using? It's also not clear if you've got a problem, or just don't like seeing the boot messages, or are just asking for an explanation of boot messages.  Sorry your question is confusing.

Comment: My apologies,  I'm new to ubuntu and I don't know very much about it I just want to resolve this error in my Ubuntu 20.4 LTS Gnome based.

Comment: Ps My Ubuntu doesn't boot it just shows the black screen with some ACPI ERROR showing on it.